# Run PHP script in Node.js (or CMD)?

Tags: node.js, shell, cmd, php-7

Due to some reasons in need to run a small part of my **NodeJS** Project in **PHP7**.
I know I can make an internal API but that would increase network dependency.

To solve this problem I found that this can be done as

```
php test.php
```

How do I provide a ***JSON input*** to this ***PHP file*** where data is stored in a JS variable not in file and receive output in another JS variable.

```
function runPHP(jsonString){
    ....what to write here
    ...
    return output_string;
}
```

> **Note**: Please, do not suggest Query parameters as the data is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to call a php scipt from a nodejs process, send some arguments in JSON and get back some JSON and process it further.

The php script:

```
<?php
// test.php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

$json = '';

while ($line = fgets($stdin)) {
    $json .= $line;
}

$decoded = \json_decode($json);

$decoded->return_message = 'Hello from PHP';

print \json_encode($decoded);

exit(0);
```

The nodejs script:

```
// test.js
function runPHP(jsonString) {
  const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  const child = spawn('php', ['test.php']);

  child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

  child.stdin.write(jsonString + '\n');

  child.stdin.end();
}

runPHP('{"message": "hello from js"}');
```

This will need some polishing and error handling...

Comment: This is more than what need to start. :) Thanks